# Select picklist value on File upload

Tags: lightning-aura-components, files, apexinputfile

Is it possible to create a Lightning Component that allows the user to upload a File and then select a picklist option to categorize that file?

For example - http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/09/25/file-upload-lightning-component/

This solution would be perfect if an extra piece could be added to allow the user to select a picklist value and then hit "upload".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you could do that.

I'm guessing you're new to Lightning development.  I would start with some of the [basic Trailhead modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics) to get a feel for how everything comes together.  Then take a look at the documentation for the [lightning:fileUpload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation) and [lightning:select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/example) components.

Let us know if you get stuck along the way.  Plenty of folks here who are happy to help.